# How do torrent uploader generate video file specs and preview?

Tags: video, video-streaming, torrent

On the different Torrent websites, how does the uploaders generate the video file specs as well as the images preview. Is this all done automatically?

An example of a torrent description can be seen here: http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/11273201/Lets.Be.Cops.2014.BRRip.XViD-juggs[ETRG]

```
Format          :  Audio Video Interleave           
Bitrate         :  799 kbps                             
Resolution      :  640 X 344                      
Aspect Ratio    :  1.85:1                    
Frame Rate      :  23.976 fps                       
Quality Frame   :  0.151

Audio :-                                             

Codec ID        :   MP3                                
Bitrate         :   128kbps                         
Channel(s)      :   2                                 
Sample Rate     :   48.0 KHZ 

Encoder         :   juggs                               
File Size       :   700MB                              
Duration        :   01h44m                             
Source          :   720 SPARKS            
Release Date    :   23-10-2014                         
Language        :   English                             
Subtitles       :   English       
Sample          :   Yes

http://i.imgur.com/xf26QG4.png 
http://i.imgur.com/ITZKIKA.png 
http://i.imgur.com/b9uT7Th.png 
http://i.imgur.com/3W4kiMy.png
```

Answer (score 0):

The information from the media file displayed is extracted using the application 'mediainfo'. The screenshots are usually done using custom scripts using other applications that can extract the screenshots and then place them in a folder inside the torrent directory and create a new torrent from them as well as posting the screenshots to the torrent tracker when it makes the upload. This is all automated and either done on the webserver or on an external server running a torrent auto uploader script.

If your goal is to have the mediainfo and the screenshts posted automatically on your site I would recommend google with something like "torrent auto uploader", or "mediainfo autopost torrent" or similar stuff.